# Debug Linux Kernel ARM64

Tags: ida, kernel-mode, arm64, debug

I need to extract Initramfs from the kernel.
The initramfs archive itself is encrypted and located inside the kernel.
I couldn't extract the key.
I thought to run the kernel in Qemu, connect with the debugger and dump it.
But this kernel does not want to start in any way, although the Ubuntu stock kernel starts without problems.
The core is made for the Allwinner H616 (Cortex-a53) platform.
Maybe someone knows how to dump initramfs or run kernel?

`qemu-system-aarch64 -machine virt -m 128 -cpu cortex-a53 -smp 2 -kernel linus -s -S -nographic`

[image: Kernel dump from dtb]

Comment: please do not post a picture of text... post the text instead